# Shopify ajax cart - Currency not updating without refresh?

Tags: jquery, shopify, liquid

In Shopify, when i change the currency, the correct and new price is displayed on my products. However, if i add a product via ajax to the cart, it uses the old price.

If i do a:

```
console.log(cart.currency)
```

I can see that the currency of the cart is NOT being updated to the newly selected value.
However, if i manually refresh the page, the correct currency is then being displayed?

Any advice on what i can do here? New to shopify so any advice as to where to look is appriciated.

Comment: Does this happen everytime or just the once and forever more it is fixed?